# Installing angular bootstrap toggle

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm learning Angular 2 so still not familiar with how it implements plugins.
I'm trying to implement **angular bootstrap toggle**:
http://ziscloud.github.io/angular-bootstrap-toggle/

Instructions say: 
*As soon as you've got all the files downloaded and included in your page you just need to declare a dependency on the ui.toggle module:
**angular.module('myModule', ['ui.toggle']);***

I'm not sure what that means. I just got used to declaring them in package.json and app.module.ts.

I don't see anywhere in these files where I might add that line.

package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "arv2",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
...
    "mydatepicker": "^2.0.21",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
...
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.4.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0"
  }
}
```

and app.module.ts looks like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER  } from '@angular/core';
...
import { CustomFormsModule } from 'ng2-validation';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SwitchClientComponent,
        SwitchClientPipe,
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
    ...
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

finally, the actual page I'm trying to implement it on looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-switch-client',
  templateUrl: './switch-client.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./switch-client.component.scss']

})
export class SwitchClientComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this **angular bootstrap toggle** is a concept for AngularJS and not for Angular2.
So you should search for a Plugin, that run on Angular 2.

If you need no text inside, you can look here
https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/overview

And if you want to use the bootstrap switcher, maybe this is one for you
[jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2)